# Problem with filling an Array of structs and then printing them in the correct order

Tags: arrays, c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "funcs.h"
#define N 500
int main() {
    int n;
    char k,c;
    struct route A[N];
    do
    {
        scanf("%c",&k);
        while ((c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n');
        switch (k)
        {   
            case 'i':   n = readFromInput(A);
                        break;
            case 'p':   printData(A,n);
                        break;
            case 'l':   findShort(A,n);
                        break;
            case 's':   findLocation(A,n);
                        break;
            case 'u':   findUpHill(A,n);
                        break;
            case 'd':   findDownHill(A,n);
                        break;
            case 'h':   findAltitude(A,n);
                        break;
            case 't':   findTimely(A,n);
                        break;
        }
        scanf(" ");
    }
    while (k!='q');
    return 0;
}
```

this is my .h file that has all the functions needed for my program to run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 500
struct route
{
    char ekk[50],term[50];
    int mikos,anav,katav,maxh,minh;
};
void bubbleSort(struct route array[], int x) {
    struct route temp;
    for (int step = 0; step<x; step++) {
        for (int i = step+1; i < x; i++) {
            if (array[step].mikos < array[i].mikos) {
            temp = array[step];
            array[step] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int readFromInput(struct route a[]){
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        fgets(a[i].ekk,50,stdin);
        a[i].ekk[strlen(a[i].ekk)-1] = '\0';
        scanf("%d%d%d%d%d\n",&a[i].mikos,&a[i].anav,&a[i].katav,&a[i].maxh,&a[i].minh);
        fgets(a[i].term,50,stdin);
        a[i].term[strlen(a[i].term)-1] = '\0';
        
    }
    return n;
}
int swap(struct route a[],struct route merge[],int n){
    char temp[50];
    struct route copy[N];
    int j=0,z=0,temp2;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(strcmp(a[i].ekk,a[i].term)!=0){
            copy[j]=a[i];
            strcpy(copy[j].term,a[i].ekk);
            strcpy(copy[j].ekk,a[i].term);
            copy[j].anav=a[i].katav;
            copy[j].katav=a[i].anav;
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n+j;i++){
        if(i<n){
            merge[i]=a[i];
        }
        else{
            merge[i]=copy[z];
            z++;
        }
    }
    return n+j;
}
void printData(struct route a[],int n){
    struct route merge[N];
    int x=swap(a,merge,n);
    bubbleSort(merge,x);
    float xronosef,xronosanav=0;
    float telikos[x];
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        xronosef=(merge[i].mikos)/65.00f;
        if(merge[i].anav>0)
            xronosanav=(merge[i].anav)/10.00f;
        telikos[i]=xronosef+xronosanav;
        xronosanav=0;
        xronosef=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        printf("From %s to %s\n",merge[i].ekk,merge[i].term);
        printf("Uphill %d, Downhill %d\n",merge[i].anav,merge[i].katav);
        printf("Max altitude %d, Min altitude %d\n",merge[i].maxh,merge[i].minh);
        printf("Length %d, Estimated time %.0f min\n\n",merge[i].mikos,telikos[i]);
    }
}
void findShort(struct route a[],int n){
    int L,j=0;
    scanf("%d",&L);
    struct route shortt[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(a[i].mikos<=L){
            shortt[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    printData(shortt,j);
}
void findLocation(struct route a[],int n){
    char loc[50],temp[50];
    int j=0,value1,value2;
    struct route loct[n];
    fgets(loc,50,stdin);
    loc[strlen(loc)-1] = '\0';
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        value1=strcmp(loc,a[i].ekk);
        value2=strcmp(loc,a[i].term);
        if(value1 == 0){
            loct[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if( value2==0 ){
            loct[j]=a[i];
            strcpy(loct[j].term,a[i].ekk);
            strcpy(loct[j].ekk,a[i].term);
            loct[j].anav=a[i].katav;
            loct[j].katav=a[i].anav;
            j++;
        }
    }
    bubbleSort(loct,j);
    float xronosef,xronosanav=0;
    float telikos[j];
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        xronosef=(loct[i].mikos)/65.00f;
        if(loct[i].anav>0)
            xronosanav=(loct[i].anav)/10.00f;
        telikos[i]=xronosef+xronosanav;
        xronosanav=0;
        xronosef=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("From %s to %s\n",loct[i].ekk,loct[i].term);
        printf("Uphill %d, Downhill %d\n",loct[i].anav,loct[i].katav);
        printf("Max altitude %d, Min altitude %d\n",loct[i].maxh,loct[i].minh);
        printf("Length %d, Estimated time %.0f min\n\n",loct[i].mikos,telikos[i]);
    }
}
void findUpHill(struct route a[],int n){
    struct route up[n];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(a[i].anav>a[i].katav){
            up[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    bubbleSort(up,j);
    float xronosef,xronosanav=0;
    float telikos[j];
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        xronosef=(up[i].mikos)/65.00f;
        if(up[i].anav>0)
            xronosanav=(up[i].anav)/10.00f;
        telikos[i]=xronosef+xronosanav;
        xronosanav=0;
        xronosef=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("From %s to %s\n",up[i].ekk,up[i].term);
        printf("Uphill %d, Downhill %d\n",up[i].anav,up[i].katav);
        printf("Max altitude %d, Min altitude %d\n",up[i].maxh,up[i].minh);
        printf("Length %d, Estimated time %.0f min\n\n",up[i].mikos,telikos[i]);
    }
}
void findDownHill(struct route a[],int n){
    struct route down[n];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(a[i].anav<a[i].katav){
            down[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    bubbleSort(down,j);
    float xronosef,xronosanav=0;
    float telikos[j];
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        xronosef=(down[i].mikos)/65.00f;
        if(down[i].anav>0)
            xronosanav=(down[i].anav)/10.00f;
        telikos[i]=xronosef+xronosanav;
        xronosanav=0;
        xronosef=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("From %s to %s\n",down[i].ekk,down[i].term);
        printf("Uphill %d, Downhill %d\n",down[i].anav,down[i].katav);
        printf("Max altitude %d, Min altitude %d\n",down[i].maxh,down[i].minh);
        printf("Length %d, Estimated time %.0f min\n\n",down[i].mikos,telikos[i]);
    }
}
void findAltitude(struct route a[],int n){
    int min,max,j=0;
    scanf("%d",&min);
    scanf("%d",&max);
    struct route fa[n],merge[N];
    int x=swap(a,merge,n);
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        if(merge[i].maxh<=max && merge[i].minh>=min){
            fa[j]=merge[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    bubbleSort(fa,j);
    float xronosef,xronosanav=0;
    float telikos[j];
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        xronosef=(fa[i].mikos)/65.00f;
        if(fa[i].anav>0)
            xronosanav=(fa[i].anav)/10.00f;
        telikos[i]=xronosef+xronosanav;
        xronosanav=0;
        xronosef=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("From %s to %s\n",fa[i].ekk,fa[i].term);
        printf("Uphill %d, Downhill %d\n",fa[i].anav,fa[i].katav);
        printf("Max altitude %d, Min altitude %d\n",fa[i].maxh,fa[i].minh);
        printf("Length %d, Estimated time %.0f min\n\n",fa[i].mikos,telikos[i]);
    }
}
void findTimely(struct route a[],int n){
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    struct route ant[n],merge[N];
    int x=swap(a,merge,n);
    float xronosef,xronosanav=0,telikosf;
    int telikos;
    bubbleSort(merge,x);
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        xronosef=(merge[i].mikos)/65.00f;
        if(merge[i].anav>0)
            xronosanav=(merge[i].anav)/10.00f;
        telikos=xronosef+xronosanav;
        telikosf=xronosef+xronosanav;
        xronosanav=0;
        xronosef=0;
        if(telikos<T){
            printf("From %s to %s\n",merge[i].ekk,merge[i].term);
            printf("Uphill %d, Downhill %d\n",merge[i].anav,merge[i].katav);
            printf("Max altitude %d, Min altitude %d\n",merge[i].maxh,merge[i].minh);
            printf("Length %d, Estimated time %.0f min\n\n",merge[i].mikos,telikosf);
        }
    }
}
```

First of all,I'm sorry for my variables as most of them are named in greek.

**The program is supposed to take multiple hiking routes, with information regarding each route and printing them with filters by the user**

this program (as you can see from the function `readFromInput`) scans `n`, n  is how many hiking routes are there for the program to scan `a.ekk`and`a.term` are the start and ending point of the route(string with whitespaces) `a.mikos` is the length `a.anav` is the uphill `a.katav` is the downhill `maxh` and `Minh` are the max and lowest altitude

In the program you must consider that in every route you go from the start to the end and then back. Nothing from the information changes except start and ending point, the uphill and the downhill and the estimated time of the route.
this does not apply when the start and ending point are the same places

**FIRST PROBLEM**

**INPUT EXPAMPLE:**

I

Limni Triadiou

591 591 744 153 11100

Limni Triadiou

Mikro Papigo

989 42 1928 977 5919

Katafygio Astrakas

Katafygio Astrakas

891 344 2496 1774 6118

Gamilla II

Elati

115 83 1002 777 3300

Gefyri Agiou Mina

Katafygio Astrakas

394 9 2443 1919 1311

Astraka

Katafygio Astrakas

295 202 2002 1745 2764

Drakolimni

p

Mind that the routes must be descending by their length and when you print the routes you always have to output the one that you typed in the keyboard AND THEN the inverse one(that's the problem in some cases here)

[My output and the Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47lVp.png)

**text form from the photos above**

**MY OUTPUT:**

From Limni Triadiou to Limni Triadiou

Uphill 591, Downhill 591

Max altitude 744, Min altitude 153

Length 11100, Estimated time 230 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Gamilla II

Uphill 891, Downhill 344

Max altitude 2496, Min altitude 1774

Length 6118, Estimated time 183 min

From Gamilla II to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 344, Downhill 891

Max altitude 2496, Min altitude 1774

Length 6118, Estimated time 129 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Mikro Papigo

Uphill 42, Downhill 989

Max altitude 1928, Min altitude 977

Length 5919, Estimated time 95 min

From Mikro Papigo to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 989, Downhill 42

Max altitude 1928, Min altitude 977

Length 5919, Estimated time 190 min

From Elati to Gefyri Agiou Mina

Uphill 115, Downhill 83

Max altitude 1002, Min altitude 777

Length 3300, Estimated time 62 min

From Gefyri Agiou Mina to Elati

Uphill 83, Downhill 115

Max altitude 1002, Min altitude 777

Length 3300, Estimated time 59 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Drakolimni

Uphill 295, Downhill 202

Max altitude 2002, Min altitude 1745

Length 2764, Estimated time 72 min

From Drakolimni to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 202, Downhill 295

Max altitude 2002, Min altitude 1745

Length 2764, Estimated time 63 min

From Astraka to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 9, Downhill 394

Max altitude 2443, Min altitude 1919

Length 1311, Estimated time 21 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Astraka

Uphill 394, Downhill 9

Max altitude 2443, Min altitude 1919

Length 1311, Estimated time 60 min

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

From Limni Triadiou to Limni Triadiou

Uphill 591, Downhill 591

Max altitude 744, Min altitude 153

Length 11100, Estimated time 230 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Gamilla II

Uphill 891, Downhill 344

Max altitude 2496, Min altitude 1774

Length 6118, Estimated time 183 min

From Gamilla II to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 344, Downhill 891

Max altitude 2496, Min altitude 1774

Length 6118, Estimated time 129 min

From Mikro Papigo to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 989, Downhill 42

Max altitude 1928, Min altitude 977

Length 5919, Estimated time 190 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Mikro Papigo

Uphill 42, Downhill 989

Max altitude 1928, Min altitude 977

Length 5919, Estimated time 95 min

From Elati to Gefyri Agiou Mina

Uphill 115, Downhill 83

Max altitude 1002, Min altitude 777

Length 3300, Estimated time 62 min

From Gefyri Agiou Mina to Elati

Uphill 83, Downhill 115

Max altitude 1002, Min altitude 777

Length 3300, Estimated time 59 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Drakolimni

Uphill 295, Downhill 202

Max altitude 2002, Min altitude 1745

Length 2764, Estimated time 72 min

From Drakolimni to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 202, Downhill 295

Max altitude 2002, Min altitude 1745

Length 2764, Estimated time 63 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Astraka

Uphill 394, Downhill 9

Max altitude 2443, Min altitude 1919

Length 1311, Estimated time 60 min

From Astraka to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 9, Downhill 394

Max altitude 2443, Min altitude 1919

Length 1311, Estimated time 21 min

**(the picture above highlights where exactly is the error)**

**SECOND PROBLEM**

the function `findShort(A,n)` scans a length L and prints all the routes equal and shorter than L

**INPUT EXPAMPLE:**

I

Limni Triadiou

591 591 744 153 11100

Limni Triadiou

Mikro Papigo

989 42 1928 977 5919

Katafygio Astrakas

Katafygio Astrakas

891 344 2496 1774 6118

Gamilla II

Elati

115 83 1002 777 3300

Gefyri Agiou Mina

Katafygio Astrakas

394 9 2443 1919 1311

Astraka

Katafygio Astrakas

295 202 2002 1745 2764

Drakolimni

L

3300

[My output and the Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDtwP.png)

**text form of the picture above**

**MY OUTPUT**

From Elati to Gefyri Agiou Mina

Uphill 115, Downhill 83

Max altitude 1002, Min altitude 777

Length 3300, Estimated time 62 min

From Gefyri Agiou Mina to Elati

Uphill 83, Downhill 115

Max altitude 1002, Min altitude 777

Length 3300, Estimated time 59 min

From Drakolimni to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 202, Downhill 295

Max altitude 2002, Min altitude 1745

Length 2764, Estimated time 63 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Drakolimni

Uphill 295, Downhill 202

Max altitude 2002, Min altitude 1745

Length 2764, Estimated time 72 min

From Astraka to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 9, Downhill 394

Max altitude 2443, Min altitude 1919

Length 1311, Estimated time 21 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Astraka

Uphill 394, Downhill 9

Max altitude 2443, Min altitude 1919

Length 1311, Estimated time 60 min

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

From Elati to Gefyri Agiou Mina

Uphill 115, Downhill 83

Max altitude 1002, Min altitude 777

Length 3300, Estimated time 62 min

From Gefyri Agiou Mina to Elati

Uphill 83, Downhill 115

Max altitude 1002, Min altitude 777

Length 3300, Estimated time 59 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Drakolimni

Uphill 295, Downhill 202

Max altitude 2002, Min altitude 1745

Length 2764, Estimated time 72 min

From Drakolimni to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 202, Downhill 295

Max altitude 2002, Min altitude 1745

Length 2764, Estimated time 63 min

From Katafygio Astrakas to Astraka

Uphill 394, Downhill 9

Max altitude 2443, Min altitude 1919

Length 1311, Estimated time 60 min

From Astraka to Katafygio Astrakas

Uphill 9, Downhill 394

Max altitude 2443, Min altitude 1919

Length 1311, Estimated time 21 min

**(the picture above highlights where exactly is the error)**

**EDIT:MY EXACT PROBLEM IN PROBLEM 1 AND EXPLAINING IT**

Basically every hiking route starts from a starting point and ends to an ending point.But you must also consider that once you came to the ending point you must go back to the starting point( for example: if my route is from London to Manchester I must also consider the Manchester to London route . this does not happen if the start and ending point are the same places).Why would u ask? because the uphill and downhill variables are inverted so the estimated time changes. Basically if I insert the route From London to Manchester. When I am printing the route there's a "rule". The route that I typed ("From London to Manchester") Should be printed first  and then the ("From Manchester to London"). My program makes a good job printing it like that in the most cases. but as you can see from the pictures some routes don't apply that "rule", it prints the inverted route and then the original

Comment: Please provide textual information as text, not as picture of text. Similar to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Comment: Could you describe in English what is wrong with your output? Do I interpret correctly that you basically sort correctly, but the order of "to" and "from" is incorrect by being swapped?

Comment: OT:regarding: `while ((c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n');`  and `char k,c;`  1) the function: `getchar()` returns a `int`  not a `char`.  2) depending if a char is signed or unsigned in your implementation. it might never be able to match `EOF` (I.E. -1) 3) regarding: `scanf("%c",&k);` and `switch (k)
        {   
            case 'i':`  this will fail if the user enters capital letters. Suggest using `toupper()` or `tolower()` found in `ctype.h`

Comment: do not put executable code in a *.h file.  Rather just put declarations and prototypes in header files..   Put the actual functions in a *.c file  and link both *.c files into your executable